# Getting a hasMany relationship inside a document with MongoDB and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, moloquent

Just trying to do some relationship on Laravel with MongoDB, but I'm getting a null on my requests.
I have a "passengers" collection with a trip_id. Something like this:

```
{  
   "id":"5d680fd36882d19e782d67bd",
   "trip_id":"5d680fcb6882d19e782d6380",
   "name":"Lee Jones"
}
```

And a collection with the name "lotes" that contain documents that each one has many trips. Something like this:

```
{  
   "_id":"5d680fca6882d19e782d60f6",
   "user_id":"5d680fca6882d19e782d60b4",
   "date_to_ride":"2019-08-29T22:00:00.000+00:00",
   "trips":[  
      {  
         "trip_id":"5d680fcb6882d19e782d6380",
         "car":"VW Golf"
      }
   ]
}
```

So I want to get all passengers that has same trip_id when I'm getting the trip info.

This is my relation on the Trip model:

```php
public function passengers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Passenger::class, 'trip_id', 'lotes.trips.trip_id')->whereNotNull('trip_id');
}
```

And this is my result on the json:

```
"passengers": []
```

Any idea?

Comment: isn't MongoDB non relational database?

Comment: Is not, but you can do relationships: https://moloquent.github.io/master/relations/

Comment: Please try with `return $this->hasMany(\App\Passenger::class, 'trip_id');` and see what you get.

Comment: Getting three passengers that has the `trip_id` with the `null` value. That's the reasson to use `->whereNotNull('trip_id');`

Comment: IMHO your Trip model primary key is null.

Comment: I don't think so, because I have other relation that works if I use it. It's weird.